# Apache Gremlin Filter returns empty when the vertex/edge is not present

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

Apache Gremlin Filter returns empty when the vertex/edge is not present.

```
g.V('12336', '4128', '155808').as("a").filter(
  __.V().has('end_time', p.gte('---DATE---')).where(P.neq("a"))).elementMap()
```

In the above query, `__.V('155808').has('end_time', p.gte('---DATE---'))` returns empty(), so the output also empyt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` (or in this case you could equally use `where`) is just that a "filter". The values in the stream will only flow past the filter if the filter itself yields a result. By way of a simple example:

```java
gremlin> g.V(1).out().count()
==>242

gremlin> g.V(1).filter(out().count().is(1))
// No results

gremlin> g.V(1).filter(out().count().is(242))
==>v[1]
```